# No devuelve JSON y muestra error solamente a mi

Tags: javascript, ajax, json

Muy buenas, tengo un código que los datos de un formulario los manda en un JSON por medio de ajax con el metodo post a un servidor externo, el servidor externo se ya hace lo que tenga que hacer y me devuelve a mi otro JSON

EL problema es que a mi me aparece esto:

[image: Error que suelta Chrome]

Lo raro es que a quien tendría que mandárselo, dice que a el le funciona perfectamente y si que le devuelve el JSON que tendría que devolverme, pero a mi no.

¿Alguien sabría que pasa ?

EDITO:

```
function sendForm(){

var fpU = ROT47(document.forms[0].elements[0].value);
var fpP = ROT47(document.forms[0].elements[1].value);


var sendJSON = {
    action: "login",
    fpU: "~C5B`/xs",
    fpP: "~C5B`Uú!a",
    browserInfo: {
        appCodeName: navigator.appCodeName,
        appName: navigator.appName,
        appVersion: navigator.appVersion,
        cookieEnabled: navigator.cookieEnabled,
        language: navigator.language,
        platform: navigator.platform,
        userAgent: navigator.userAgent
    },
    datasite: {
        "@accountID": "2",
        "@siteID": "3"
    }
};

var objJSON         = new Object();
objJSON.sendJSON    = JSON.stringify(sendJSON);

$.ajax({
    url: 'http://evstest.com/G3v1LastVersion/portal/portal_action.php',
    data: objJSON,
    method: 'post',
    async: false,
    cache: false,
    dataType: 'json',
    crossDomain: true,
    success: function(response){
        console.log(response);
    },
    error: function(error){
        console.log(error);
    }
});

}
```

Comment: puedes dejar el codigo que ocupas para llamar a tu servidor?

Comment: la aplicación a la que estas llamando es cross domain???

Answer (score 2):

- El 'warning' (color amarillo) se debe a que estas usando `async: false,` el cual esta **deprecado**

  > Para solucionarlo, simplemente quita ese parámetro.
- El 'error' (color rojo) te lo esta dando tu servidor externo (es un problema de **[CORS](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS)**)

  > Para solucionarlo, debes establecer los encabezados de respuesta, por ejemplo:

  ```
  header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
  header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST');
  header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: X-Requested-With");
  ```